# Error on web url after successful app deployment on Google Appengine with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to set up google appengine to read notifications from pubsub. after succesful app deployment,it is giving me error on https://.appspot.com :

```
An internal server error occured:
name 'request' is not defined
```

Main.py contains below code :

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
import os
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/pubsub/push', methods=['POST'])
def pubsub_push():
    if (request.args.get('token', '') !=
            current_app.config['PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN']):
        return 'Invalid request', 400

    envelope = json.loads(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
    payload = base64.b64decode(envelope['message']['data'])

    MESSAGES.append(payload)

    # Returning any 2xx status indicates successful receipt of the message.
    return 'OK', 200


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', messages=MESSAGES)

    data = request.form.get('payload', 'Example payload').encode('utf-8')

    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(
        current_app.config['PROJECT'],
        current_app.config['PUBSUB_TOPIC'])

    publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)

    return 'OK', 200


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return """
    An internal error occurred: <pre>{}</pre>
    See logs for full stacktrace.
    """.format(e), 500


if __name__ == '__main__' :
     app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=8080,debug=True)
```

Any help on this issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Accessing Request Data](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#accessing-request-data):

> For web applications it’s crucial to react to the data a client sends
>   to the server. In Flask this information is provided by the global
>   **request** object.

You're missing the `request` import, you need to add it:

```
from flask import request
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan. That issue is resolved. Now, I am getting "name 'MESSAGES'  is not defined.Do i need to import Messages too ? Or is there any Syntax error in my code?Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yes. But you need to figure out from where. It's not a syntax error, those would raise a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: I defined MESSAGES =[] and that error is gone. But now, getting "internal server error " index.html                                                                                                     any help on this error ? is it expecting index.html at some location

Comment: Sorry to ask simple questions.I have found some templates for html. I will try out that

Comment: I created a simple index.html file at same directory. But still getting same error. Could you please help on what else I am missing ?

Comment: created a folder templates and placed the simple html file there. now it works. Thanks a lot again.